# Javascript: visual issue when dragging image by eventListener

Tags: javascript, dom-events, drag

I'm making a script to drag an image in a frame using `eventListener` instead of `.onSomeEvent`:

```
var destForm, destFoto, destX, destY;
function destaqueIni(){
    destForm = document.forms["form_destaque"];
    destFoto = new Object();
    destFoto.img = document.getElementById("form_destaque_foto");
    destFoto.w = destFoto.img.clientWidth;
    destFoto.h = destFoto.img.clientHeight;
    destFoto.x = 0; //Number(destForm.fotoDestaque_x.value);
    destFoto.y = 0; //Number(destForm.fotoDestaque_y.value);
    destFoto.escala = Number(destForm.fotoDestaque_escala.value);
    //
    document.getElementById("form_destaque_janela").style.height = "380px";
    //
    destFoto.img.draggable = true;
    destFoto.img.addEventListener("dragstart", destaqueFotoDragStart, false);
    destFoto.img.addEventListener("dragend", destaqueFotoDrag, false);
}
function destaqueFotoDragStart(evt){
    //evt.preventDefault();
    //console.log("destaqueFotoDrag: Foto Arrastada... img.x: "+evt.clientX+" destX: "+destX);
    destX = evt.clientX;
    destY = evt.clientY;
}
function destaqueFotoDrag(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    //console.log("destaqueFotoDrag: Foto Solta... img.x: "+evt.clientX+" destX: "+destX);
    var x = destFoto.x + (evt.clientX-destX);
    var y = destFoto.y + (evt.clientY-destY);
    destForm.fotoDestaque_x.value = x;
    destForm.fotoDestaque_y.value = y;
    destaqueFotoAtualizar();
}
function destaqueFotoAtualizar(){
    destFoto.img.style.left = String(Math.ceil(destForm.fotoDestaque_x.value/2))+"px";
    destFoto.img.style.top = String(Math.ceil(destForm.fotoDestaque_y.value/2))+"px";
}
```

It works (still working, but is dragging). So the image will be moved but before the image be placed at the new x,y coordinates, the browser do an animation back to the original place - after it jumps to the right place. This is a pretty bug! How do I prevent the browser from making the animation after release? I tried `preventDefault()` but didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Search "stop drag image in browsers" and you will get your answer.

```
$("img").mousedown(function(){ return false; });
$(document).on("dragstart", function() { return false; });
$(document).on("dragstart", function(e) {
     if (e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "IMG") { return false; }
});
<div onmousedown="event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false">asd</div>
<div onmousedown="return false">asd</div>

//also css has selection rules for different browser
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using jQuery this time. Also, I'm implementing events by addEventListener method.